Incompleteness of infinite dimensional Banach space with weak topology.
Suppose  is an infinite dimensional Banach space. I need to prove that  with weak topology and it's dual * are incomplete with $weak$ and $weak$* topology respectively. All I've seen is the theorem which says that the weak dual of a locally-convex topological vector space $V$ is complete if and only if every linear functional on $V$ is $continuous$.
It is I have to find an unbounded operator in the second case. But I don't know what to do in the first one. Probably it would be easier to find a Cauchy net that does not converge, but I haven't seen any statements and ideas that would help...

$X$ endowed with $\sigma(X,X^)$ can be identified with the weak dual of $X^$ endowed with $\sigma(X^*,X)$, so you can again use the result about locally convex spaces you mentioned.

Finding a discontinuous linear functional is not easy -- it requires, e.g., a Hamel basis of the Banach space or some other nonconstructive choice principle.

@Jochen, Suppose {$v_\alpha$} is a Hamel basis of our space and {$v_n$} is its countable subset. It is easy to see that the linear functional $$l(x) = \sum_n n*v_n$$ is unbounded on the unit sphere. So we found our discontinuous linear functional. Am I right? But I am more interested in finding divergent Cauchy net, and I don't know what how to find one...

Wlog all $v_\alpha$ have norm $1$ and we denote by $v_\alpha^$ the dual functional, i.e., $x=\sum v_\alpha^(x)v_\alpha$ for every $x\in X$ with only finitely many $v_\alpha^(x)\neq 0$. Then $\ell(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} nv_{\alpha(n)}^(x)$ for a sequence $\alpha(n)$ of distinct indies is well-defined, linear, and discontinuous. The proof of the result you mention in the post yields that $X^$ is dense in the algebraic dual (both endowed with the topology of pointwise convergence on $X$). There is thus a net in $X^$ onverging to $\ell$.  This net is Cauchy in $X^*$ without a limit.
